# How to add a second ssh public key to authorized_keys file in the server?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys, openssh, ssh-keygen

I have setup a VPS and I have set my public key in the server from my main machine, now I generated a new set of keys in a work machine (secondary laptop) and copied that into the .ssh/authorized_keys file but I get always the following: Permission denied (publickey). Why does this happen? I have tried numerous times but I cannot set a second public key into the authrized_keys file.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.